# Import IntelliSense support from Visual Studio Code to Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-code, intellisense

As title, is there any way to Import IntelliSense support from Visual Studio Code to Visual Studio 2013?
I found some language they do not have intelliSense support for Visual Studio 2013/2015, but they do have it for Visual Studio Code via typings.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer this is not possible as I also was looking for go support and only VS Code has it. VS Code and VS are completely different products and they are not compatible together.